# WPF : Multiple binding of RectangleGeometry

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to write a WPF program to select a partial region on the image.
The whole image except the selected region must be semi-transparent.
And the selection should be resized by moving the corners.

[image]

For the first step, I was going to make the whole image as semi-transparent except the selected part.

I had created a model representing the selection rectangle and was going to bind to the RectangleGeometry, but I had got the such error in the converter (Convert function in RectConverter2 class).

"System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'"

Here is my code

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="CropImage.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:CropImage.Converters"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:CropImage.ViewModels"
        >
  <Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <converters:RectConverter x:Key="RectConverter"></converters:RectConverter>
      <converters:RectConverter2 x:Key="RectConverter2"></converters:RectConverter2>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Window.Resources>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <vm:CropWindowModel />
  </Window.DataContext>
  <Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
    <Grid>
      <Image x:Name="imgViewer" Source="Penguins.png" Stretch="Uniform" >
      </Image>
    </Grid>
    <Canvas Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=mainGrid}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=mainGrid}">
      <Path Fill="#80C3C3C3" Cursor="Cross" x:Name="backgroundPath">
        <Path.Data>
          <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Exclude">
            <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
              <RectangleGeometry>
                <RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                  <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource RectConverter}">
                    <Binding ElementName="mainGrid" Path="ActualWidth"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="mainGrid" Path="ActualHeight"/>
                  </MultiBinding>
                </RectangleGeometry.Rect>
              </RectangleGeometry>
            </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
            <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
              <RectangleGeometry>
                <RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                  <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource RectConverter2}">
                    <Binding Path ="CropWindowModel.CropLeft" Mode="TwoWay" />
                    <Binding Path ="CropWindowModel.CropRight" Mode="TwoWay" />
                    <Binding Path ="CropWindowModel.CropWidth" Mode="TwoWay" />
                    <Binding Path ="CropWindowModel.CropHeight" Mode="TwoWay" />
                  </MultiBinding>
                </RectangleGeometry.Rect>
              </RectangleGeometry>
            </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
          </CombinedGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
      </Path>
    </Canvas>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

CropWindowModel.cs

```
namespace CropImage.ViewModels
{
  public class CropWindowModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    private double _cropLeft;
    public double CropLeft
    {
      get => _cropLeft;
      set
      {
        _cropLeft = value;
        OnPropertyRaised("CropLeft");
      }
    }
    private double _cropRight;
    public double CropRight
    {
      get => _cropRight;
      set
      {
        _cropRight = value;
        OnPropertyRaised("CropRight");
      }
    }
    private double _cropWidth;
    public double CropWidth
    {
      get => _cropWidth;
      set
      {
        _cropWidth = value;
        OnPropertyRaised("CropWidth");
      }
    }
    private double _cropHeight;
    public double CropHeight
    {
      get => _cropHeight;
      set
      {
        _cropHeight = value;
        OnPropertyRaised("CropHeight");
      }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyRaised(string propertyname)
    {
      if (PropertyChanged != null)
      {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

RectConverter.cs

```
namespace CropImage.Converters
{
  public class RectConverter : IMultiValueConverter
  {
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
      return new System.Windows.Rect(0, 0, (double)values[0], (double)values[1]);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
  }

  public class RectConverter2 : IMultiValueConverter
  {
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
      return new System.Windows.Rect((double)values[0], (double)values[1], (double)values[2], (double)values[3]);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
  }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

If you know the similar sample or open source, it would be also grateful.

Comment: `Path="CropWindowModel.CropLeft"` seems invalid when the DataContext is a CropWindowModel instance. Try `Path="CropLeft"`.

Comment: Yes, right.
It works after replace with "CropLeft".
Thank you, @Clemens.
If you write an answer  separately, I will accept you as the best answer.
Do you know the similar sample or open source?

Comment: As a general hint, take a look at the Output Window in Visual Studio when you debug your application. It will show data binding errors like this. Also set breakpoints to investigate variable values during debugging. You would have noticed that the values array does not contain any double values.